# How to have a view in ConstraintLayout behave as both wrap_content and match_parent depending on visibility of another view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

As you can see in the image below, I'm looking for a way to have 2 views, and I need that when both are visible, view 2 behave as a wrap_parent, but when view 1 is gone, I will like to view 2 to take the remaining of the space.

I know constraint layout can accomplish this; I haven't found a way to do it.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for[image]

**Edit 1**

Neither of these views is view groups.

Comment: did you try  width at 0dp int View 2?

Comment: yup what it end up happening is that both take half and half, I could try using weights to make the view1 take 3/4 of the space but it's not really what I'm looking for :D

Comment: the width ofth view1 is fixed ?

Comment: No, view1 should take as much space once view 2 has its space calculated.

Comment: if I understood correctly neither view 1 nor view 2 have a predefined dimension ?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: if view 1 is a ViewGroup you can set its width depending on the width of these children, with an `android: maxWidth =" "` to not overwrite the view 2. and in your View 2 you can set the width to 0dp with `app: layout_constraintStart_toEndOf =" @ id / view1 "`

Comment: These 2 views are not View groups, both are actually textviews!

Comment: I tested that I had said on the previous message on the TextView it seems to me that what you want to do! please check [this](https://imgur.com/DDcrS8f) result on the gif

Comment: Not exactly, in the provided example view1 should have taken most of the space and left view2 behaving as wrap_content, then when view1 disappear view2 should fill out all the space!

Comment: you can just vary the min width of view 1, int in the provided example i have set it at 100dp

Comment: yeah but view1 has no fix width, I can't predict the minWidth because it depends on view2 `wrap_content` behaviour, but when view1 is gone this behaviour should change to match_parent

Comment: yes the width of view 1 depends on the size of the text but by specifying the min with we can make view 1 take the majority of the width, but this does not prevent view 2 from having a wrap_content

Comment: The text can be as short as "Welcome here" but view1 still should take all the remaining space of view2.

When view1 disappear view2 should take all the remaining space that view1 left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place both views into a horizontal chain that is `spread_inside`. Set the width of both views to `0dp`. For *View 2*, specify `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"`. For *View 1* set the layout weight (`app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`) to `1`.

The following XML is an example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="View 1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="View 2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When both views are visible, we see this:

[image]

With *View 1* `gone`, we see this:

[image]

Comment: Two things would improve this answer, in my opinion. (1) add `layout_goneMarginStart` to the second view. (2) clarify that you must use `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` and not `android:layout_weight` (though your code already does this).

Comment: @BenP. You read my mind. I was just addressing that in an update.